# Saving and reading an object in an AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I am a beginner when it comes to coding and I have been having some trouble with an object that has been written to a file in android. That object(arraylist) comes from an api and I can get it to populate my textviews when there is an internet connection by executed my asynctask. The problem is if there isn't an internet connection I want the asynctask to pulled the data from a local file. My question is I'm not sure of the best place to put the IF statement to check for the connection and pulled from the saved file. Any help would be appreciated.

public class SearchFrag extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {

```
final String TAG = "micgrams";

//INSTAGRAM AUTHENTICATION
private static final String CLIENT_ID = "e79ad9e2173443deb8eea89ef21b15e9";
private static final String CLIENT_SECRET = "d2d64643a7ec4595b4c871d28c59bbf3";
private static final String REDIRECT_URI = "http://clear.com/instagram/access-token";


boolean isConnected;
boolean newtworkBool;
Button search;
EditText searchText;
ConnectionTest connection;
Communicator comm;


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag_search, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    connection = new ConnectionTest(getActivity());
    isConnected = connection.isConnectedToInternet();
    comm = (Communicator) getActivity();
    searchText = (EditText) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.searchInput);
    search = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.searchBtn);
    search.setOnClickListener(this);


}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    Log.d(TAG, " CLICKED!");
    Log.d(TAG, "it's Working");

    //GETS VALUE OF SEARCHFIELD AND SENDS IT TO
    String result = searchText.getText().toString();

    Log.d(TAG, "result: " + result);

    URL searchForURL = null;
    try {
        isConnected = connection.isConnectedToInternet();
        searchForURL = new URL((makeUrl(result)));

        if (isConnected) {
            Log.d(TAG, "New CONNECTED!");
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), " Connected!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            new getInstadata().execute(searchForURL);

        } else if (!isConnected) {


                Log.d(TAG, "NO CONNECTION FOUND");
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), " NO CONNECTION FOUND!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                FileInputStream fis = getActivity().openFileInput("myFile");
            new getInstadata().execute(searchForURL);


            }


    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
}

//ASYNCTASK CLASS THAT PARSES THE DATA FROM INSTAGRAM
public class getInstadata extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, JSONObject> {

    final String TAG = "realfragments ASYNCTASK";
    //DECLARES THE VARIABLES FROM THE ITEMS THAT WILL BE RECEIVE FROM INSTAGRAM
    public ArrayList<String> pics = new ArrayList<String>();
    public ArrayList<String> user = new ArrayList<String>();
    public ArrayList<String> fullname = new ArrayList<String>();
    public ArrayList<Bitmap> searchPic = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();

    @Override
    protected JSONObject doInBackground(URL... urls) {


        String jsonString = "";
        for (URL searchURL : urls) {
            try {
                URLConnection conn = searchURL.openConnection();
                jsonString = IOUtils.toString(conn.getInputStream());
                newtworkBool = true;
                break;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Could not establish URLConnection for " + searchURL.toString());

            }
        }

        Log.d(TAG, "Received Data: " + jsonString);

        JSONObject instagInfo;
        JSONArray instaArray;
        MicSearch readMic;

        try {
            instagInfo = new JSONObject(jsonString);

            //TARGETS INSTAGRAM DATA ARRAY
            instaArray = instagInfo.getJSONArray("data");
            String thisPic;
            String thisBio;
            String thisUser;
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {

                instagInfo = instaArray.getJSONObject(i);

                //GETS IMAGE FROM INSTAGRAM AND ADD IT TO THE ARRAYLIST
                thisPic = instagInfo.getJSONObject("images").getJSONObject("standard_resolution").getString("url");
                pics.add(thisPic);

                //GETS FULL NAME FROM INSTAGRAM AND ADD IT TO THE ARRAYLIST
                thisBio = instagInfo.getJSONObject("user").getString("full_name");
                fullname.add(thisBio);

                //GETS USER NAME FROM INSTAGRAM AND ADD IT TO THE ARRAYLIST
                thisUser = instagInfo.getJSONObject("user").getString("username");
                user.add(thisUser);


            }

            Log.d(TAG, "username" + user);
            Log.d(TAG, "full_name" + fullname);
            Log.d(TAG, "url" + pics);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            instagInfo = null;
        }

        try {
            Bitmap pulledImage = getBitmapFromURL(pics.get(0));
            searchPic.add(pulledImage);

        } catch (Exception e) {


        }

        try {

            if (newtworkBool) {

                readMic = new MicSearch(user.get(0), fullname.get(0), pics.get(0));
                readMic.setUserName(user.get(0));
                readMic.setRealName(fullname.get(0));
                readMic.setUserImg(pics.get(0));

                FileOutputStream fos = getActivity().openFileOutput("myFile", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                ObjectOutputStream of = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
                of.writeObject(readMic);
                of.flush();
                of.close();
                fos.close();
                Log.d(TAG, "saving......." + readMic);
                Log.d(TAG, "......" + readMic.getUserName() + readMic.getRealName());



        }else if (!newtworkBool) {


            FileInputStream fis = getActivity().openFileInput("myFile");
            ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
            readMic = (MicSearch) ois.readObject();
            ois.close();


            Log.d(TAG, "readingOff....." + readMic);
            Log.d(TAG, "......." + readMic.getUserName() + readMic.getRealName());

            Bitmap pulledImage = getBitmapFromURL(readMic.getUserImg());
            searchPic.add(pulledImage);
            //comm.Communicate(readMic.getUserName(), readMic.getRealName(), searchPic.get(0));





            }




        }catch (Exception e) {
        }


        return instagInfo;
        }


    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);

    }


    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        //ProgressBar progress = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar3);
        //progress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    }

    //SETS THE INSTAGRAM/ARRAY ITEMS FOR DISPLAY TO THE USER
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject jsonObject ) {
        super.onPostExecute(jsonObject);
      MicSearch readMic = null;
        if(newtworkBool){
            comm.Communicate(user.get(0), fullname.get(0), searchPic.get(0));
        }else if(!newtworkBool){
            comm.Communicate(readMic.getUserName(), readMic.getRealName(), searchPic.get(0));
        }

            doInstagram();
        }

    }
```

Comment: Can you post your full AsyncTask, and where you call `execute()`?

Comment: Your code looks good. Are you able to load the file?

Comment: As far I can see, you have put it in onClick(), so I find it perfect where have you put your `if` condition.

Comment: I am not able to load the file from the IF statement that is in onClick. When I try  android studio  cannot resolve the object saved to the file. It's like it doesn't see the file or the object pulled from the API in the AsyncTask.

Comment: not answering your question, just want to point out that its good to print cause of the exception, avoid empty catch blocks (it just hides your error), don't over use try & catch block.

Comment: Thanks for the help everyone but I was unable to get my app to work with the full network check in doInBackground.  I had to split it up between onPostExecute to get past a compile error. My app works if there is a connection present, saves the object and reads the object if NO connections is present. I see in my Log that it's reading the object but I can't get it to appear in my textviews. I have updated my code. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm not sure of the best place to put the IF statement to check for
>   the connection and pulled from the saved file

In `doInBackground`.

Because both checking network connection and fetching data from api is related to network related task. system will take time in performing both tasks.

Comment: When I put the network check in doInbackground it worked, but it only showed the first item in the object. I'm not sure why this is happening. my app would read the entire object when i Logged it but only the first Item gets put into the textview. Thanks for any advice.